# FreeNAS plugins won't load

Tags: truenas

I recently set up my first server using FreeNAS, and have it up and running on my internal LAN. When I installed, I saw a list of plugins available, but I didn't install any at the time. Today, I went back to my FreeNAS setup, clicked the Plugins button, and saw "unexpected token <" in the status window. I clicked Refresh, and it says "No entry has been found." I know that there are plugins available, but why are they suddenly not available?

Please let me know what further information I can provide. As I am very new to FreeNAS, and servers in general, I'm not sure where to find logs or anything like that. If someone tells me, I'll be glad to retrieve and post.

```
Build FreeNAS-9.3-STABLE-201502142001  
Platform Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3225 CPU @ 3.30GHz  
Memory 7869MB
```

**Update 1:**
I just ran `tail -f /var/log/debug.log` and saw this line when I refreshed my plugins list:

```
cmd_pipe.__init__: err = ERROR: No available repos!
```

At least this gives me a clue. Gonna keep searching.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you have a jail set up?

Comment: Review the time setting and reboot the system... Additional info at: https://bugs.pcbsd.org/issues/12590

Answer (score 1):

mine, FreeNAS 9.3.1 Stable.
Fix with

1. Network > IPv$ Default Gateway : "Your router value" please see http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/finding-your-default-gateway/
2. Network > Nameserver 1: 8.8.8.8
3. Network > Nameserver 2: 8.8.4.4

[image: webgui freenas "Network" tab]

Answer (score -2):

I know this is kind of old, but I fixed my instance of this with a single command. reboot. Simple, but effective.